# C program loop input

Tags: c

I'm working on a project for my C programming class for a program that takes user input either from the keyboard or a text file and then prints out the number of each character in the file.
I've managed to get it to output to the console using stdout but am having difficultly getting it to output to a file when the user uses "-o".

It keeps giving me `BADFILE` (`NULL`) whenever  I use `./counts apple.txt` or `./counts apple.txt -o appleresults.txt`

```
        if(argv[i] = "-o")
        {
            fp = fopen(argv[i+1], "w");
            if(fp == 0)
            {
                BADFILE(argv[i+1])
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I think it has to do with the `if(argv[i]="-o")` loop but I can't seem to solve the error.

Comment: Use `strcmp(argv[i], "-o") == 0` to compare strings.

Comment: Equality test is `==`, assignment is `=`, and strings are just pointers - you can't compare strings by testing the equality of pointers.  These are the absolute basics of C.  Perhaps you need to work through an introductory book on C.

Comment: Okay got it. I understand the difference between == and = but I missed it when reading through the code.

Comment: Please don't delete your code from the question, again.

Comment: Again, don't modify your code like that, it would make the current answer pointless.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by Yu Hao, your string compare is wrong (you are actually assigning the value `"-o"` to `argv[i]`)

You might want to check the `argv[i+1]` is a valid string.

I can't see you declaration of `fp` but I'm assuming it's a `FILE*`.

To write output into the file use `fputs(char* , FILE*)`
And finally don't forget to close the file when you're done.