# Comparing addresses of character array

Tags: c

So it give me an error using if(argv[i]=="-o").
Is there a different function  I can use.

Comment: Didn't you see [my comment on your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21896013/c-program-loop-input#comment33158684_21896013)? Use `strcmp()` to compare strings.

Answer (score 1):

You can't compare strings like this in C:

```
if(argv[i]=="-o")
```

That just compares the addresses of the character arrays.

What you need is:

```
if(strcmp(argv[i],"-o") == 0)
```

This actually runs through the 2 strings and returns 0 if all characters are the same.

Answer (score 0):

The first loop tries to open all the parameters as files, so if a -o occurs before a filename, it will try to open the file "-o"

You are comparing a string with ==, which won't do what you are intending, as it only compares the pointers, not the string itself. try strcmp instead

If the -o is the last parameter you will get a memory fault, as when you find a -o, you then blindly read from argv[i+1], even if i=argc-1